# How to make table of contents using Html tags in IText7 & PdfHtml?

Tags: itext7, pdfhtml

I want make table of contents using Html tags in IText7 & PdfHtml.
but, I referred to the answer information for the existing question,
internal link information for table of contents was not properly converted.

1. In the past, we implemented the table of contents using CSS leader ('.') option,
   but it did not work properly with IText7. By any chance, how can I use it in IText7, pdfHTML?
2. When converting html to PDF using IText7, pdfHTML, the href information for <a>Tag was not properly converted. By any chance, is there a way to convert only IText7?
   (<a> We created # + 'id' information in the href attribute of the tag, and added the id information entered in the href to the id attribute of the tags <h2> and <h3>)

Suppose you converted the html below to pdfHTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-of-contents" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <h1>Table of contents</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href='#chapter1'>Chapter 1</a>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href='#chapter1-1'>Chapter 1-1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#chapter1-1'>Chapter 1-2</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#chapter1'>Chapter 2</a>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href='#chapter2-1'>Chapter 2-1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#chapter2-1'>Chapter 2-2</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div>
    <h1 id='chapter1'>Chapter 1</h1>
    <div>
        <h2 id='chaptor1-1'>Chapter 1-1</h2>
        <div>
            Chapter1-1 Content.....
        </div>
        <h2 id='chaptor1-2'>Chapter 1-2</h2>
        <div>
            Chapter1-2 Content.....
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1 id='chapter1'>Chapter 2</h1>
    <div>
        <h2 id='chaptor2-1'>Chapter 2-1</h2>
        <div>
            Chapter2-1 Content.....
        </div>
        <h2 id='chaptor2-2'>Chapter 2-2</h2>
        <div>
            Chapter2-2 Content.....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. For the above questions, the CSS is written as below.
   However, when you perform a conversion operation using the Html Converter in pdfHTML,
   a leader-unsupported message appears.

```
.table-of-contents ol a::after {
      content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page);
}
```

2. <a> When you click on a tag, it does not move inside the document,
   but to the actual href link. Do I have to do a link in Backend to make it a document link in IText7?